# get and sort JSON array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I've read all of the related questions on here but nothing seems to work for me.  I'm trying to take information from a .json file and sort it by nearest date to today and then present all the information relating to that event.

events.json

```
[
 {
  "title":"Event 1",
  "start": "2014-12-06T09:00:00"
 },{
  "title":"Event 2",
  "start": "2014-12-11T09:00:00"
 },{
  "title":"Event 3",
  "start": "2014-12-13T10:00:00"
 }
]
```

jQuery

```
$.getJSON( "events/events.json", function(data){
    var array = $.map(data, function (item, index) {
    console.log([item.title, item.start]);
    });
});
```

Instead of, as I expected, showing me Array[3] (and then the events, start date) in the console, it shows me

```
["Event 1", "2014-12-06T09:00:00"]
["Event 2", "2014-12-11T09:00:00"]
["Event 3", "2014-12-13T10:00:00"]
```

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT:  Thanks for all the help so far, but I think I've not been very clear with what I'm after.  I want to get the data to display

```
Array[3]
  {"Event 1", "2014-12-06T09:00:00"}
  {"Event 2", "2014-12-11T09:00:00"}
  {"Event 2", "2014-12-13T10:00:00"}
```

so that I can sort the array by date, if they are all in sub arrays, or their own arrays, I cant sort them against each other (or if I can, I don't know how, and didn't know you could!)

Comment: the console logs objects thats small enogth completly, so `[item.title, item.start]` is only a length of 2, u can try to store it in an array and log it after to get an other output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well you simply want to display an array of 3 tuples instead of three arrays.

```
var parentArray = [];
$.getJSON( "events/events.json", function(data){
    $.map(data, function (item, index) {
        parentArray.push( { 'title': item.title, 'start': item.start } );
    });
});
console.log(parentArray);
```

Your result will be:

```
[
    { 'title': 'Event 1', 'start': '2014-12-06T09:00:00' },
    { 'title': 'Event 2', 'start': '2014-12-11T09:00:00' },
    { 'title': 'Event 3', 'start': '2014-12-13T10:00:00' }
]
```

Comment: I dont want the three tuples to be arrays.  I want them to be {'label':'value', 'label2':'value2'} if you understand me, so that they can be sorted by date.

Comment: Brilliant, that's done it.  I was trying to bring the value names with it from the JSON file rather than just setting them new ones that are the same, which is a much better idea!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery map function has two arguments. Index and item. Index comes first.

You want an array of arrays. Each inner array will have the two values.

So write

```
$.getJSON( "events/events.json", function(data){
    var vals = [];
    var array = $.map(data, function (index, item) {
        vals.push([item.title, item.start]);
    });
    console.log(vals);
});
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c0uzhp4m/2/)

Comment: even with index and item switched it still displays as before, 3 arrays of 2 items instead of the desired one array of 3 items with 2 values each.

Comment: sorry for this. i updated my answer and jsfiddle too

Comment: That's put the Array[2]'s inside an Array[3] but i'm trying to get it so it's a bunch of {value:thing, value:thing} inside an Array[3] so then they can be sorted

Answer (score 0):

use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) sortBy and do something like

```
$.getJSON( "events/events.json", function(data){
    var now = new Date();
    var sortedArray  = _.sortBy(data, function (item) {
            return CALCULATEDIFFBETWEENDATES(now,item.start);
        });
});
```

Comment: If I do this, everything in the console becomes 'undefined'.

Comment: You should implement some things, if you expect that everybody solves all the problems without using a single piece of effort that's not right man

Comment: I did implement some things, and they didn't work, hence I asked about it.  If that isn't what this place is for then please, enlighten me

Comment: Did you implemented CALCULATEDIFFBETWEENDATES, did you included underscorejs file? Did you read the doc? Mine was just a guide.

Comment: yes, I did all of those things, and it came up with undefined in the console.  I did eventually get it to work (because I did those previously mentioned things), and your method was still incorrect.

Comment: Probably that is because I answered your original question which was not what you wanted to achieve, but " I'm trying to take information from a .json file and sort it by nearest date to today and then present all the information relating to that event."
Then you edited with something completely different.

Comment: I didn't I provided clarification as to the format I was looking to achieve so that the information _could_ be sorted, which it couldn't if everything was in it's own array.  Hence my edit.  You seem to have taken this all very personally for some reason.